# Prove that $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic if and only if there is a primitive root modulo $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic **if and only if** there is a primitive root modulo $m$.

if $g$ is a primtive root modulo $m$ so indeed  $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic by definition , but I don't understand why the other direction is right:

if  $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic then it has a generator g, but how do we know that $\gcd (m,g)=1$ and that $g\in (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$  ?

Comment: Otherwise $\;g\;$ wouldn't have order equal to $\;m-1\;$...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem here is understanding well the definitions:$$\left(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\right)^*\;\;\text{cyclic}\iff \exists\,a\in\left(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\right)^*\;\;\text{such that}\;\;\left(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\right)^*=\langle a\rangle\iff a^{\phi(m)}=1$$

and this isn't true for any exponent less than $\;\phi(m)\;\iff\;a\;$ is a primitive root modulo $\;m\;$

Comment: I believe the order of $\left(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\right)^\times$ is $\phi(m)$, not $m-1$.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw Thank you, of course you're right. Missed the point htat $\;m\;$ isn't a prime. Editing now.

Answer (score 2):

If $ g $ is *any element* of the group $ (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times} $, that means $ g $ has an inverse modulo $ m $, which means that there are integers $ a, b$ such that $ ag + bm = 1 $. By Bezout's identity, this implies that $ \gcd(g, m) = 1 $. Of course, any generator of a group must be an element of the group, so the result follows.

Comment: really helped me! :)